# Displaying an image larger than the device's screen

Tags: android, image, resize, scroll, android-imageview

I'd like to display an image larger, in size, than a device's screen without resizing the image.  It has to be centered on the screen.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use scrollview with image view and set height of that scroll view

### Example

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/accountIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: This worked great for me! Only issue was that the ImageView was not centered after doing this, so then I only had to add `layout_gravity="center"` to the ImageView. Also note that, in modern Android, [fill_parent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#FILL_PARENT) is deprecated and can be safely replaced by [match_parent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#MATCH_PARENT) in all cases (as they both do the exact same thing).

Answer (score 5):

I noticed that I need to use normal (vertical) and horizontal ScrollView in order to scroll both directions. Let me know please if there is another way.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView" >
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:src="@drawable/big_map"/>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

It started display form left upper corner of the image. If I tried to use android:layout_gravity="center" then I got white part on right or bottom. So centering is not working for me.

Option 2: use WebView control, and load it with image onCreate.

Answer (score 0):

Derive from View, overwrite onDraw and draw it on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can also work with framelayout. The layout can be bigger than the screen